# D3DXMatrixRotationQuaternion in DirectX 9: How Does This Function Operate

Tags: math, matrix, libgdx, directx, quaternions

I've got a fully working camera perspectives demo written in DirectX 9.0 which I'm trying to translate to my LibGDX game engine.

The issue I'm having is that the DirectX functions like D3DXMatrixRotationQuaternion() take in a matrix and a quaternion and alter the matrixbut nothing and no one seems to want to tell me how it does it, exactly.

What is the math inside of the function? I suspect this information is only a few lines of code so that I can replicate the simple math inside my game engine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: LibGDX has its own Matrix4 and Quaternion classes. Since its open source, you can look at the Matrix4.rotate(Quaternion) method to see how the math works.

Comment: Only if that code is identical to the original function I need to replicate. If not, then it wont work. - EDIT: I just did look at it. Its not even close to the same thing.